# Rearrange Methods in IntelliJ: visibility first, dependencies 2nd

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to configure IntelliJ IDE (v2017.1, Ultimate Edition) so that it re-arranges my methods in the following order (using Settings / Editor / Code Style / Java) when I do "Rearrange":

1. According to visibility: public methods first, private methods last (in practice, I only have public and private methods)
2. According to dependencies, i.e. to the call order, as implemented with the option "Keep dependent methods together / depth-first order".

However, the 2nd rule is always prioritized so that public and private methods are mixed once I enable the "Keep dependent methods together" option. Is there a way to change the order of these different types of rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please vote for the related request in YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148129

Comment: I reckon the implied answer is: "it is (currently) not possible"